# iOS - APNS how to use loc_key in payload

Tags: ios, localization, apple-push-notifications

I have a message string i want to localize before i let APNS send a message to devices.  I wish i could see the json payload itself to make me understand the structure instead of the device parsing it out for me. but anyway, how do i use the loc_key and loc_args argument ? from the docs i found:

> loc-key
>   string
>   A key to an alert-message string in a Localizable.strings file for the current localization (which is set by the user’s language preference). The key string can be formatted with %@ and %n$@ specifiers to take the variables specified in the loc-args array. See Localized Formatted Strings for more information.
>
> loc-args array of strings Variable string values to appear in place of
>   the format specifiers in loc-key. See Localized Formatted Strings for
>   more information.

and it was offical doc is [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/Chapters/ApplePushService.html)

I need a concrete example of how to localize a string and what is loc_args ?

I am just guessing here, but  if i have a string localized like this:
mystring="cool localized message"
then the loc_key will be "mystring", is that right ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

loc-key is a string that needs to match a key in your Localizable.strings file inside the app bundle. For example if the loc-key is "my-push.hello-world" and you have the following line in your Localizable.strings file:

```
"my-push.hello-world" = "Hello, World!";
```

the push message displayed to the user would read "Hello, World".

log-args are strings that will be replaced in the message, like your have it in `[NSString stringWithFormat:@"blabla %@"];`

Apples example is this:

Push Notification Payload:

```
"alert" : { 
    "loc-key" : "GAME_PLAY_REQUEST_FORMAT",
    "loc-args" : [ "Jenna", "Frank"]
}
```

Localizable.strings content:

```
"GAME_PLAY_REQUEST_FORMAT" = "%@ and %@ have invited you to play Monopoly";
```

Answer (score 2):

#### if loc key is there, loc_key refers to a key in your localizable file...

e.g. if `loc_key=XYZ`, then there must be an entry `"XYZ"="translated XYZ";` in the apps' localizable file.

#### loc_args is an array of strings that is to be inserted into the translated string as if you had used `stringWithFormat:`

e.g `loc_args=["DOMI", "ME"]` inserted into a translated XYZ like `%@ is %@` results in `"DOMI is ME"`