# Xamarin.IOS Handle remote notifications when app is killed

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios

I have a question about handling remote notifications when an app is killed (i.e. manually removed from recent apps).

Let me give you some background information first.

We have a server that sends remote notifications to iOS devices by using APNS. We process the notification in the app and store it on the device itself.

When the app is in the foreground, DidReceiveRemoteNotification() is called, and we can process the notification. We then display a local notification.

When the app is in the background (not killed), DidReceiveRemoteNotification() is also called, and we can process the notification. The notification is automatically displayed as a local notification.

**PROBLEM**

When the app is killed, DidReceiveRemoteNotification() is not called, so we can not process the notification. However, the notification will be shown as a banner.

When the application is killed it displays the lock-key text in the notification.  I need you to show that custom text according to that lock-key. Thank you very much

PUSH =>

```
{{
aps =     {
    alert =         {
        "loc-args" =             (
        );
        "loc-key" = "new_chat";
    };
    "content-available" = 1;
    id = 3;
    message = Aaa;
    sound = default;
    subject = "new_chat";
    type = chat;
};}}
```

Answer (score 0):

iOS will not automatically relaunch your app and call `DidReceiveRemoteNotification` if the user has force-quit. Review the **"Discussion"** section of the [`didReceiveRemoteNotification`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiapplicationdelegate/1623013-application?language=objc) API:

> ...
>
> However, the system **does not automatically launch your app if the user has force-quit it**. In that situation, the **user must relaunch your app or restart the device** before the system attempts to launch your app automatically again
>
> ...

Apple iOS Docs: [application:didReceiveRemoteNotification:fetchCompletionHandler:](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiapplicationdelegate/1623013-application?language=objc)

Comment: I don't want to reluch my application. I want to modify the notification message displayed when the application is dead. Right now it shows the text that goes in the lock-key.

Comment: @MiguelAngelMuñoz ??? iOS is not foreground launching your app if it is not in the foreground when DidReceiveRemoteNotification is called, that is happening in the background but will not happen at all if the user has force quit the app. If you want a different notification message then send a different message from your server.

Comment: I need to change the message when the user forces to quit the application. Can I show one message or another based on that key?

Comment: @MiguelAngelMuñoz You could just use silent notifications, or localize the notification on your server before sending to APNS, use a generic message for abbreviated banner and also use a notification content app extension with a matching category in your APN category value to display a custom version of notification if the user taps that notification to display the full notification interface (and thus your extension app can create a custom view).

Comment: I think that what I have to use is this but I do not work on xamarin the localizable => https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33762317/ios-apns-how-to-use-loc-key-in-payload

Comment: @MiguelAngelMuñoz Include your localization strings within the UNNotificationServiceExtension app that is within your main app bundle.

Comment: Do you know any examples?

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use [Voip push notification](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/Performance/Conceptual/EnergyGuide-iOS/OptimizeVoIP.html)

But it will causes launch of app.

We have same problem with relaunching, so after app is launched by notification we handle it and kill app programmaticaly(I know it is bad idia to kill app, but workflow of our system requiresthis)

Comment: If your app is not actually a VoIP app, the App store reviewers are going to reject it.